# Can I have Office Online Server 2016 without Exchange?

Tags: oos

We currently have Exchange 2010 and are planning to deploy SharePoint 2016 Enterprise.  The question I have is, can we also deploy Office Online Server 2016 as well?  What are the integration points or features that would be miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Office Online Server is a stand alone product that has no other dependencies. You would miss 'modern attachments' (requires Exchange 2016) as well as document previews in OWA (requires Exchange 2013 or higher).

Comment: So I got a little more clarification from the consultant.  The say "you cannot have Project Server Features and BI Features in the same Site Collection".  This still confuses me after I reviewed the TechNet documentation on Project Server which uses BI Tools like PowerBI.